# iptables -L not showing all rules?

Tags: linux, ip, iptables, sniffing, forwarding

I've added this rule with iptables:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -j TEE --gateway 192.162.122.62
```

I've checked it with iptables -L or iptables -S but I can't see anything.
Is that normal? how can I remove it then?

Comment: ok I can see everything using     iptables -t mangle -S

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command for the Netfilter rules in the iptables.

iptables -vL -t filter

iptables -vL -t nat

iptables -vL -t mangle

iptables -vL -t raw

iptables -vL -t security

Regards,